# Modifying allowed orientations on MPMoviePlayerViewController (called from UIWebView). iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app working on iOS 5 and 6. This app must run only in portrait mode (it's done). But in this app I have to show and play some YouTube videos.

To achieve this I use a `UIWebView` to show the thumbnail YouTube video. So, I have a nice thumbnail and when the user touches it the app shows automatically a `MPMoviePlayerController` playing the video. Almost all is perfect...

My problem is that I need the `MPMoviePlayerController` supports both orientation (but only this controller). How could I achieve this?

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Comment: if you find solutions on your question, Please update the post.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the desired orientations to your Info.plist
2. Subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController
3. Override shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations to return YES and all the orientations you wish to support, respectively.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any control over the MPMoviePlayerController because it is created automatically by the UIWebView

Comment: When the user touches the thumbnail to play the video, isn't the phone launching the youtube app to play the video? That is, isn't the video playing in another app at that point?

Comment: No, it launches a MPMoviePlayerController. When Safari and UIWebView detect a YouTube link they draw an image of the video and when you push on it, they launch the MPMoviePlayerController.